# $document.injector is not a function in Karma E2E Tests

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing, angular-scenario

I have been trying to resolve this from a month now but no luck yet. I am doing E2E(End-to-End) testing using karma and ng-Scenario for my angular application running on server. I know there is a more robust tool(Protractor) available for end to end testing but for some reason I have to use ng-scenario only.
I am proxing the IP address of my application though karma server as shown below in my Karma config file.

---

I am getting error `$document.injector is not a function` on my chrome browser as well as in console. One thing which I doubt might be causing problem is that the app is getting all the data once it loads(It's a single page application). But don't know weather it is actually the problem behind the issue or not.

Secondly the port of my application is being redirected which may be causing the issue.

Or Thirdly I think, may be there's some problem with network gateway route(My system's IP).

**My karma Config File**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

    basePath : '../',

    files : [
             'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
              'bower_components/angular-1.3.15/angular-mocks.js',
              'test/e2e/application/scenarios.js',// or 'test/e2e/**/*.js'
            ],

    autoWatch : true,
    urlRoot : '/__karma/',
    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    frameworks : ['ng-scenario'],

    singleRun : false,

    proxies : {
        '/' : 'http://10.10.5.56:0080/',
    },

    reporters : [ 'progress', 'htmlalt'],
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    plugins : [ 
                'karma-jquery',
                'karma-chrome-launcher',
                'karma-firefox-launcher',
                'karma-jasmine',
                'karma-ng-scenario',
                'karma-htmlfilealt-reporter',
                'karma-mocha',
                'karma-chai',
                'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
                'karma-jasmine-matchers',
                'karma-bdd-using',
            ],
    htmlReporter : {
        outputFile : 'output/E2E.html',
        // Optional
        pageTitle : 'End to End',
        subPageTitle : 'Karma-Jasmine Automation Test Framework Report'
    },

})}
```

**My Scenarios File**

```
'use strict';
describe('Application Login and Logout', function() {
    var spyEvent;
    beforeEach(function() {
        browser().navigateTo('../index.html');
        console.log("Something in beforeEach");
    });

    // test default route
    it('should navigate to correct page', function() {
        console.log("Something in IT before expect");
        expect(browser().location().path()).toBe('/login');
        console.log("Something in IT after expect");
    });

    it('User is able to login application with valid credentials', function() {

        console.log("Something again");
        expect(browser().location().path()).toContain("/login");

        input('username').enter('motzieadmin@qasource.com');
        input('password').enter('admin');
        element('button').click();

        expect(browser().location().path()).toContain("/home");

    });
});
```

**The Error I am getting**

```
    browser navigate to '../index.html'
11ms    $location.path()
http://localhost:9876/base/test/e2e/application/scenarios.js:13:10

TypeError: $document.injector is not a function
    at ChildScope.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js:27819:30)
    at angular.scenario.Application.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js:27698:18)
    at angular.scenario.Application.executeAction (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js:26854:19)
    at ChildScope.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/karma-ng-scenario/lib/angular-scenario.js:27671:22)
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong. There may be some problem with path. Help is appreciated.

Comment: `ng-scenario` is deprecated long ago. If you are starting new projects use `protractor`

Comment: @bhantol I know about protractor and I am using it in my other projects but ng-scenario has been used in my application's tests from long time.